# Вертикальное меню активный пункт, выпадающее меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

не могу разобраться, как сделать выпадающий список на пункт меню "Услуги" и при нажатие на Услуги- становился активным(фон зеленый, как и у остальных пунктов меню) , а выбранный подпункт видимый, а остальные подпункты светлого цвета

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var offset = $('#fixed').offset();
  var topPadding = 10;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
      $('#fixed').stop().animate({
        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
      });
    } else {
      $('#fixed').stop().animate({
        marginTop: 10
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.left-menu {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  min-height: 750px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#gmenu ul {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}
#gmenu li {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  /*font-weight:600;*/
}
#gmenu li a {
  display: block;
  /* Ссылка как блочный элемент */
  padding: 2px;
  /* Поля вокруг надписи */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Подчеркивание у ссылок убираем */
  color: black;
}
#gmenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #02A511;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#gmenu li a.active {
  background-color: #02A511;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-menu" id="gmenu">
  <ul class="menu" id="fixed">
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Разработка сайтов</a>
    </li>
    <li>Услуги
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Наши работы</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Акции</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Статьи</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Хостинг</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Услуги копирайта</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Вакансии</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>О нас</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: чуток доработал ответ : так надо ? http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/ORPvwG

Comment: выбираем услуги - услуги зеленый фон, потом нажимаем на 1 -1 черная а 2 и 3  не активные, а остальные пункты меню, как и обычно

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".submenu").click(function(){
  $(".submenu ul").slideToggle();
  $(".submenu").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.left-menu {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  min-height: 750px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
ul.menu {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}
ul.menu li {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.menu li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

ul.menu li:hover a,
ul.menu li.submenu:hover,
ul.menu li.submenu ul li:hover,
.active {
  background-color: #02A511;
  color: white;
}

ul.menu li.submenu ul {
  display: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul.menu li ul, ul.menu li.submenu ul li{
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  color: black;
}
ul.menu li.submenu ul li{
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-menu" id="gmenu">
  <ul class="menu" id="fixed">
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Разработка сайтов</a></li>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Услуги</a>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Наши работы</a></li>
    <li><a>Акции</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Статьи</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    <li><a>Хостинг</a></li>
    <li><a>Услуги копирайта</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Вакансии</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
    <li><a>О нас</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: выбираем услуги - услуги зеленый фон, потом нажимаем на 1 -1 черная а 2 и 3  не активные, а остальные пункты меню, как и обычно

Comment: Распишите подробно как выглядит до и после действия, ибо я ничего не понял.

Comment: <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Разработка сайтов</a></li>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Услуги</a>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Наши работы</a></li>
нажав на услуги (становится активным как и остальные меню, фон зеленый), список открывается, нажимаем на 1 - перехолим на страницу 1- пункт услуги активный все также, 1-черным цветом, а 2 и 3 серым